# get current customer's cart items count in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi

I want the current customer's cart items count via custom web api in Magento 2.
Please help me out to get that

Answer (score 0):

**url**

---

> http://magento.host/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items

```
method :: POST
```

> **Header** - In Authorization pass customer's token.

```
Authorization :: Bearer <customer token>
```

Comment: could you please tell how to get customer token..